# Como definir a cor da borda de uma tabela sem CSS?

Tags: html

Existe alguma maneira? Não quero CSS nem externo, nem interno, apenas html puro. Segue meu codigo.

```
<table widths="30;60" cellpadding="1.5" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p >Data:</p>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#dddddd">
                <p>@Model.DatFormulario</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assim use `bordercolor` da tag 'table':

```
 <table widths="30;60" cellpadding="1.5" border="1" bordercolor=red>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p >Data:</p>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#dddddd">
                <p>@Model.DatFormulario</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: E para manipular a borda de uma tr ou td? Não consegui fazer da mesma maneira que a table utiliza.

Comment: Fizeram uma alteração para mim, usando o bgcolor, obrigado @MatheusBessa

Comment: No firefox fica com borda 3D colorida.

Comment: A única forma que eu achei para ficar com efeito `collapsed`, é usar o truque do background/cellspacing.

Answer (score 4):

Uma das formas (e que **funciona consistentemente em todos os browsers**) é definir o background da tabela para uma cor, colocar um cellspacing, e então colorir o fundo de cada célula de branco (ou da cor que desejar), de forma que o fundo da tabela apareça entre as células, e fique parecendo uma borda:

```
<table width="728" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ff6600">
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td width="240" height="67">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="240">HTML table borders without CSS</td>
        <td width="240">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td height="67">cellspacing="2"</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>bgcolor="#ff6600"</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6652/)

Referência:

[HTML table borders without CSS](http://www.compmiscellanea.com/en/html-table-borders-without-css.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o atributo `bordercolor`

> This is the color of the border (if you have the border turned on - that is if you use the border attribute in your TABLE tag).

Que em tradução livre:

> Esta é a cor da borda (se você tiver a fronteira ligado - ou seja, se você usar o atributo fronteira na sua tag TABLE). No Netscape, isto só irá colorir o fundo e borda direita.

E você ainda pode definir o padrão para as cores claras e escuras das bordas utilizando os atributos  `bordercolorlight` and `bordercolordark`.

Estes atributos se aplicam apenas à borda externa da tabela, não existe nenhum atributo [html](/questions/tagged/html) para se manipular as bordas de `tr` e `td`, neste caso será necessário utilizar [css](/questions/tagged/css).

Answer (score 2):

Exemplos:

`HTML` com atributo `style` para uso CSS interno.

```
  <table widths="30;60" cellpadding="1.5" border="1" style="border-style:solid; border-color:#0000ff;">
```

`HTML` com atributo `bordercolor` para troca de cor.

```
  <table widths="30;60" cellpadding="1.5" border="1" bordercolor="#ff0">
```

`bordercolor -` usar uma cor em hexadecimal ou nome em inglês (red, black, green, etc).

Comment: Bom, talvez ele não queria usar arquivo externo CSS, portanto usar o atributo style é considerável. E também o CSS consegue formatar muito bem uma table.

Comment: @Eduardobrj Sim, foi isso que eu entendi.

Answer (score -1):

É possível! Basta colocar dentro da tag table:

```
<table bordercolor="aqui_a_cor_desejada">
```

Fonte: http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/88.php